# A Usercontrol for all CRUD operations as gridview via entity framework

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, entity-framework-4

I want to create a usercontrol for grid operations.  Basically I will give the data type as input and then this control  will create a grid that makes all the CRUD operations for this data type.

I have devexpress license. I can use it .

Anyone can guide me ?

Comment: just do not do it. A User Control or any other UI control should only handle data rendering and data input but "unless your project is trivial", you should have a Data Access Layer and some business logic separated from the UI (Presentation Layer), so that could be reused (and tested) easily. Imagine that if your needs change and you want to use a listview instead of a grid, you will have to reimplement your CRUD management logic... just don't do it :)

Comment: Actually I have approx. 50 tables in db and some users want to make crud operations to all the tables. Most of these tables are "dummy tables" I do not want to rewrite code again and again. For just 25 30 main tables I have business logic . But for dummy tables ,This is my case.

Comment: I am NOT saying that you should write the code many times, write it once and reuse it but put it in the BL or DAL NOT in the UI layer. Worst case you create a generic/base form which contains some calls to this business logic and you instantiate this form passing a table name then the grid calls the methods you defined in the form. Everything parametrized and working smooth but not with CRUD logic ina user control.